# How can create a Selection in the browser in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom, textselection, selection-api

The [Selection API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection) allows me to get the current selection with `window.getSelection()` and edit the selection with

```
selection.modify('extend', 'backward', 'character');
```

to, for example, go back a character.

**But how can I actually select text with the selection API?**

Comment: I find [some](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+set+text+selection+site%3Astackoverflow.com)

Comment: @mplungjan that's not a full sentence but yes I see what you mean - I'll close my question.

Comment: Yeah, could not bring myself to hammer close

Comment: The accepted answer to the linked question above has a pure JavaScript solution.